# Proving $g$ is onto if $\{(f\circ g)(x)|x\in \mathbb R\}=\mathbb R$ and $f$ is injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $f,g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $\{(f\circ g)(x)|x\in \mathbb R\}=\mathbb R$.
>
> Prove that if $f$ is an injection then $g$ is a surjection.

Since $f$ is an injection then $\exists f^{-1}s.t. f^{-1}\circ f=i_{\mathbb R}$.

Can I apply that inside the set to get: $\{(f^{-1}\circ f\circ g)(x)|x\in \mathbb R\}\overset{?}\equiv \{g(x)|x\in \mathbb R\}\overset{given}= \mathbb R$.

Since for every $y\in \mathbb R:g(x)=y :\exists x\in \mathbb R$ we get that $g$ is a surjection.

Comment: If $g(x)=y$ doesn't have a solution $x$ for some $y$, then $f(y)=(f\circ g)(z)$ doesn't have a solution $z$. If it had, then $f(y)=(f\circ g)(z)$, which implies $y=g(z)$.

Comment: Why $f(y)=(f∘g)(z)$? @Pp..

Comment: It is just an equation with unknown $z$, not an identity.

Comment: OK, I don't get what you did with the solutions here... @Pp..

Comment: Rephrasing Pp.'s argument above: assume there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $g(x)\neq y$ (i.e., assume $g$ is not surjective). Then, consider $z\stackrel{\rm def}{=} f(y)$. Since $z\in\mathbb{R}$, by assumption there exists $x^\prime$ such that $f\circ g(x^\prime)=z$, as $f\circ g$'s image is $\mathbb{R}$. But then we have $f(g(x^\prime))=z=f(y)$, and since $f$ is injective this means $g(x^\prime)=y$, contradicting the assumption that $y$ had no preimage by $g$.

Comment: @ClementC. I think I got it. I see I wasn't even close then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I suppress composition signs for brevity, writing $fg$ in place of $f \circ g$.)

We are asked to show that $\{g(x): x \in \Bbb R\} = \Bbb R$. Your observations that there exists an $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}f = {\rm id}_{\Bbb R}$ and that therefore $\{g(x): x \in \Bbb R\} = \{f^{-1}fg(x): x \in \Bbb R\}$ are entirely correct.

However, some work remains to go from the assumption $\{fg(x): x \in \Bbb R\} = \Bbb R$ to the desired conclusion $\{f^{-1}fg(x):x \in \Bbb R\} = \Bbb R$.

To this end, note that $f^{-1}fg(x) = f^{-1}(fg(x))$, so that using our assumption, we derive:

$$\{f^{-1}fg(x):x \in \Bbb R\} = \{f^{-1}(y): y \in \Bbb R\}$$

because each $y \in \Bbb R$ can be written as $y = fg(x)$ for some $x \in \Bbb R$.

Thus we are left with proving that $f^{-1}$ is surjective. But for every $z \in \Bbb R$, we have $f^{-1}f(z) = z$. Hence, each $z \in \Bbb R$ is in the image of $f^{-1}$, namely under the element $f(z)$. Therefore, $f^{-1}$ is surjective:

$$\{f^{-1}(y): y \in \Bbb R\} = \Bbb R$$

and by combining this with the equalities we derived earlier, it follows that $g$ is surjective as well.

Comment: Very clear answer. Thanks :)

Comment: You're very welcome :).

Comment: BTW, since $\{(f∘g)(x)|x∈R\}=\mathbb R$ that means that $f\circ g$ is onto right?

Comment: @GinKin That's the very definition of onto, yes.

Answer (score 1):

$\{(f\circ g)(x)\;\vert\;x\in \mathbf R\}=\mathbf R$ means precisely $f\circ g$ is a surjection. If $f$ is injective, it has a *retraction*, i.e. there's a function $r\colon  \mathbf R \rightarrow  \mathbf R$ such that $\,r\circ f=1_{\mathbf R}$.

As $1_{\mathbf R}=r\circ f$ is surjective, $r$ is surjective. Hence $r\circ(f\circ g)$ is surjective. Now  $$r\circ(f\circ g)= (r\circ f)\circ g = g. $$

Comment: What is $1_{\mathbb R}$ ?

Comment: Your argument is admittedly more elegant. I chose to connect with the OP's ideas.

Comment: @GinKin: the identity on $\mathbf R$.

Answer (score 1):

Two important facts about composition of maps. Let's consider the general case of
$\varphi\colon X\to Y$ and $\psi\colon Y\to Z$, so we can do $\psi\circ\varphi$.

> 1. If $\psi\circ \varphi$ is surjective, then $\psi$ is surjective.
> 2. If $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are surjective, then $\psi\circ\varphi$ is surjective.

Applied to our case, 1 implies that $f$ is surjective. Being injective by assumption, $f^{-1}$ exists (and is bijective). Now 2 implies that $f^{-1}\circ f\circ g$ is surjective as well. But $f^{-1}\circ f\circ g=g$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. You have the equation: ${g(x)|x \in R} = f^{-1}(R)$ and you are done if you show that $f^{-1}(R) = R$.

Comment: How and why $=f^{−1}(R)$?

Comment: You apply on the given equation the operation $f^{-1}$ on both sides.

Comment: But the functions take values in $\mathbb R$ not sets or $\mathbb R$ itself... Are you saying that $f^{-1}(\{(f∘g)(x)|x∈R\})\equiv \{(f^{−1}∘f∘g)(x)|x∈R\}$?